# How to pick/get fields from editable pdf file by PHP/Laravel? Need pdf fields name not fields value

Tags: pdf, pdfparser

I want to get editable PDF input field names by php/laravel. So that I can fill data by mapping input fields from PDF. I've tried many packages but not working with those packages.

**Used Packages:**

```bash
composer require smalot/pdfparser
composer require setasign/fpdi
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf
composer require mikehaertl/php-pdftk
composer require setasign/fpdf
```

etc packaged are tried but not working. If anyone work with this kind of things then please tell me what's the procedure?

**Thanks**